# Expand an ordered series of codes from start/end interval points

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of the following kind

```
> foo <- data.frame(start = c(7, 12, 23, 30), end = c(10, 16, 27, 35), code = rep("A", 4))
> foo
  start end code
1     7  10    A
2    12  16    A
3    23  27    A
4    30  35    A
```

my goal is to create a new data frame `series` which expands the ordered series previously compressed in start/end points, and at the same time contains a code B for the points outside the coded intervals in `foo`:

```
> series
   time code
1     1    B
2     2    B
3     3    B
4     4    B
5     5    B
6     6    B
7     7    A
8     8    A
9     9    A
10   10    B
11   11    B
12   12    A
13   13    A
...
29   29    B
30   30    A
31   31    A
32   32    A
33   33    A
34   34    A
35   35    A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map`, which is a multivariate version of `lapply`:

```
foo2 <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(s, e, c){data.frame(time = seq(s, e), 
                                                        code = c)}, 
                           foo$start, foo$end, foo$code))
head(foo2, 10)
#    time code
# 1     7    A
# 2     8    A
# 3     9    A
# 4    10    A
# 5    12    A
# 6    13    A
# 7    14    A
# 8    15    A
# 9    16    A
# 10   23    A
```

The function makes a data.frame with `time` as the `seq`uence from `start` to `end`, and `code` as the code from that row. `do.call(rbind` catches the data.frames created from each row and reassembles them.

We can then fill the remaining levels with `merge` and `is.na`:

```
foo3 <- merge(foo2, data.frame(time = 1:max(foo$end)), all.y = TRUE)
foo3$code <- as.character(foo3$code)    # change from factor to character
foo3$code[is.na(foo3$code)] <- 'B'
head(foo3, 10)
#    time code
# 1     1    B
# 2     2    B
# 3     3    B
# 4     4    B
# 5     5    B
# 6     6    B
# 7     7    A
# 8     8    A
# 9     9    A
# 10   10    A
```

If you'd rather keep your data as factor (reasonable), you can replace the two lines after the merge with:

```
foo3$code <- factor(foo3$code, levels = c('A', NA), labels = c('A', 'B'), exclude = NULL)
```

which is equivalent, except for will avoid conversion to vector.

---

If you don't mind `code` being a character vector and you've *only* got codes of "A" and "B", you can actually work backwards from a complete data.frame, and then reinsert the `"A"` values by assembling the sequence with `apply`, which is a little simpler:

```
foo4 <- data.frame(time = seq(1, max(foo$end)), code = 'B', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
foo4$code[unlist(apply(foo[,1:2], 1, function(x){seq(x[1], x[2])}))] <- 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
# create a new table with time and code columns
bar <- data.table(time = 1:max(foo$end), code = "A")
# sub-assign "B" to code column
bar[!time %in% foo[,list(start:end), by = 1:nrow(foo)]$V1, code := "B"]
```

Comment: a little bit shorter: `CJ(time = 1:max(foo$end), code = "A")[!foo[, .(start:end), by = 1:nrow(foo)]$V1, code := "B"][]`

Comment: I tried this solution and installed data.table package but some error keeps popping up after the second line (which is not very transparent to me - I should go through the package instructions I guess, which I can't do right now). Thanks anyway @docendo - this was a very compact code.

Comment: @GiuGe I forgot to include `setDT(foo)` after the library call

Answer (score 0):

Using some `sequence`s and `rep`eats:

```
out <- data.frame(
  time=seq(1, max(foo$end)),
  code="B",
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

cnts <- foo$end - foo$start + 1
out$code[sequence(cnts) + rep(foo$start, cnts) - 1] <- as.character(rep(foo$code, cnts))

out

#   time code
#1     1    B
#2     2    B
#3     3    B
#4     4    B
#5     5    B
#6     6    B
#7     7    A
#8     8    A
#9     9    A
#10   10    A
#11   11    B
#...
```